# Java method called WebEngine (by JavaScript) is not executed after first loading the content in WebEngine

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm working on an application that reads a method (`println()`) from the Java code in the JavaScript code in a local HTML file that is loaded by WebEngine when the user selects an item in ComboBox.

The method is successfully called the first time the user selects an item in ComboBox (which is the first time the content is loaded in WebEngine), but after the first time, the method is no longer executed.

If you can explain to me how to write the code in a way that the method is executed even after the first time the content is loaded in WebEngine.

My Controller.java:

```
public class Controller {

    ObservableList<String> months = FXCollections.observableArrayList
        ("Tishrei", "Cheshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet", "Shevat", "Adar",
        "Nisan", "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");

    public ComboBox<String> month;
    public WebView webView;

    public void println(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        month.setItems(months);

        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        win.setMember("app", this);

        month.setOnAction(event -> {
            String loadFile = this.getClass().getResource("index.html").toString();
            webEngine.load(loadFile);
        });
    }
}
```

The script in HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.println("Hallow World!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Right. But methods can be imported from Java code to JavaScript code as in the example above by `executeScript` (see about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-)) and the method is done, but my problem is that it only happens the first time the content is loaded in WebEngine.

Comment: So maybe you can somehow get the JavaScript code to reload on the server every time the user selects an item in ComboBox?

Comment: This is just about uploading a local file.

Comment: So does that mean it can't be done, or is it possible but not recommended?

Comment: The truth is, I don't really understand what this means with the "server", etc. I'm just trying to figure out how to apply the matter in question above to my question because this is how I can get what I need in the application.

Comment: So is there another possibility by which I can get what I need?
Still, it does not make sense to me that such a thing would not be possible. Java has invested so much to build the language in a way that it communicates with the JavaScript and they haven't made another effort to make it multi-fold?

Comment: OK. So using Ajax request can I do this?
If so then how exactly?

Comment: Well, I hope I get along. Thank you so much for the great attention and detailed comments you have given and the investment of your time.